# Why video is not showing poster image in twitter bootstrap?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to insert video in the page which i am working on. But my page is not displaying poster image. Only the video is working when played. Why?

```
<body class="page page-index">

     <!-- Button to trigger modal -->
    <a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" style="overflow:hidden" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-header" style="padding:0px 0px;">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>

      </div>

      <div class="modal-body" style="max-height:none" >

        <video controls height="480" width="480" poster="img/poster480.png">
        <source src="video/sample.mp4"  type="video/mp4">

     </video>
      </div>

    </div>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-modal.js"></script> 
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    </body>
```

Comment: which browser(s) is this happening on?

Comment: google chrome browser

Comment: I copied you code "as is" and put a small black (16 by 16) "png file" in the img folder (but no video) and the placeholder shows black. as the video had not loaded. When I include the video it still shows until I press the play button and then the video shows

Comment: Seems to work with absolute URLs, sure it's not a path thing? http://jsfiddle.net/davidpauljunior/Jzuje/2/

Answer (score 1):

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
  <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
      Launch demo modal</a>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" 
           aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
        aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
           <video controls height="400" width="400" poster="images/amit.jpg">
                <source src="images/big_buck_bunny.mp4"  type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" 
         data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
  </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Tested in Google Chrome and Firefox was working as expected.

Please note : I used bootstrap.min.js of version v2.3.1, Please check if u are using an older version.

Cheers!!